# Regex comparison in Dust

Tags: dust.js, dust-helpers

Is there a way to use regex expression comparison using dust template.

eg:
        `@select key="{notes}"}
      {@eq value="s+"}
         sample: {notes}
       {/eq}
       {@default}
         {notes}
       {/default}
     {/select}`

I want any notes with 's' as the beginning, to be printed as "sample: {notes} " else it will directly print the {notes}.

Is it possible to do so with using any external helper?

Comment: you need a helper function to return an array with string starts with 's'

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function

**Helper**

```
dust.helpers.regexp = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var regexp = new RegExp(params.pattern, params.flag);
  if (regexp.test(params.term)) {
    return chunk.render(bodies.block, context);
  } else {
    return chunk.render(bodies['else'], context);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
{@regexp term=notes pattern="^[sS](\w+)" flag="g"}
  sample: {notes}
{:else}
  {notes}  
{/regexp}
```

[DustJS helpers](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers)